# Ignite installation test going forever

Tags: maven, ignite

Very new to Ignite. I tried to do maven build with Ignite source files -

`mvn clean package -DskipTests`

The tests have been going overnight. There is still no sign of stopping. Should I just kill the test?

[test screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FX7GC.png)

Answer (score 1):

`-DskipTests` means tests should be skipped. Make sure you have entered it right.

Without tests the build usually takes 5-15 minutes depending on hardware.

Comment: Did have a typo. Compiled it just right now and it runs well. Thanks Pavel.